# Offline xml parsing on an offline html5 website without any server communication

Tags: jquery, xml, html

i want to parse XML-Data to an offline HTML5 Website (static), where both of Files running in Webbrowser on my Localhost without any Webserver. I readed many Tutorials but found there only how i can use Ajax and make a offline Website, where XML-Data already parsed, :(.
I want use HTML5, Javascript, Jquery, XML.

Have you any Idea or Experience with this? Is it possible? If yes, in wich direction should i research? Thanks a lot!

Regards
Bachka

Comment: After researching i found now this Solution for my Problem:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383590/store-xml-data-into-html5-indexeddb). I will first try it and will post later here. Regards, Bachka

Comment: Linkname is : Store XML data into HTML5 indexedDB